# Importing COLLADA Models into QGIS

Tags: qgis, model, qgis2threejs, collada

***QGIS 2.18.5***

I'm using Qgis2threejs to put this [COLLADA model](https://clara.io/view/e1f88f5e-62c5-4828-acf9-e705a6645be2/webgl) ontop of a point (open in IE, not chrome). You see how the web-preview animates perfectly and the blades are centred on the hub. When loading the model through Qgis2threejs, the 3D visualisation adds the model with the blades off-set from the hub. Is there a way to get the animation going as well?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you only a hint concerning the offset of the blades because i faced the same problem.

What I did was getting [google Sketch up](https://www.sketchup.com/) and downloaded a model from [their warehouse](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/). I then checked if the model is placed on the center of the 3 axes and if not adjusted the model accordingly. After this you can export the model as colada *.dae file and thus make it usable in threejs. You might need to set the rotation and scale values inside the plugin to fit the model to your needs.

[image]

Concerning the animation i found [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=anim#misc_animation_keys) on the threejs site. I will give it a try and keep you updated!

Comment: That's great information LaughU, thank you very much!